# Backup database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I need to backup a small database (68kb) using PHP. I don't have access to cron jobs and I am not sure if mysql dump is installed.

Any pointers or good places to start would be helpful.

Comment: phpMyAdmin would be the easy way to go about this, if you have access to it.

Comment: Do you have shell access/the ability to create shell scripts?

Comment: Do you need this to run automatically, or is it manual backup?

Comment: It uses some crappy admin panel that doesn't even have a name... I do not have access to create shell scripts and it doesn't need to run automatically.

Comment: I think the admin control panel must be one created by the hosts I've never seen one like it :P It does have a backup function that works well but the client would like a button that does the same in the CMS I have created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `system('mysqldump ...');`. You will be surprised for some really crappy share hosting environment w/o shell access, you still get to run `system()` and do your thing.

Comment: I've using `system('wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz -O - | tar x ')` to install WordPress on F**C*w once, instead of uploading 300+ files through FTP.

Answer (score 1):

One of the links that comes up in Google, perhaps solutions 1 or 2 would be fine for you:
http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx

First solution pointed there uses `LOAD DATA INFILE`, the second `system(mysqldump)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) or the older [MySQL Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)